# How to play sound when my Cast app is in background?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast, television, google-cast-sdk

The most popular Chromecast apps like Youtube and Soundcloud can continue to play music when their app is in background. How can I implement this in my Android apps? I have searched, but not found any information about this. It is so annoying for the users of my apps, when the sound always disappears when they temporarily switch to another app. It could be that they just want to check the weather or a message from a friend. It destroys the whole experience of casting my apps. Please Cast SDK team, help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

This is not expected behavior for an app that is using the cast SDK. What exactly is it that you are casting?

Playback on the device should not stop unless it is intentionally stopped - even when the sender loses network connection a started playback is supposed to resume...

Comment: I am casting my music visualizers, for instance "Astral 3D FX Music Visualizer", which can be found on the Playstore. I have followed the tutorials and guides when implementing this. The sound plays when my visualizer apps are in the foreground, but the sound pauses as soon as my apps are in the background. The sound resumes when my apps are in foreground again. Do you know how I can solve this so the sound plays all the time?